# Is this grammatical--"Look on on"

Tags: grammaticality

"As we look on on the conflict"

I want to use the phrase "look on" but am not sure how to incorporate it into the sentence. Would be "as we look on at the conflict"?

Comment: Hello, 846. Can you find (and include) a definition (or more than one) of the multi word verb 'look on'? Does a dictionary, say, give example sentences? Do they include 'look on at/on'? 'Look on as/while ...' are available, but don't transitivise, in the way 'look in **on** someone' does.

Comment: It may not be a transitive verbal, so better to look on *as* the kids play together.

Comment: It certainly can be followed by a prepositional phrase but one starting with "on" would be very awkward. People generally try to avoid repeating a word like that, because it can look and sound like a mistake. [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/look-on) and other dictionaries give examples of "look on". "On" and "at" do mean different things, so they're not entirely substitutable; I'd suggest finding different words, or even putting something between the two ons.

Comment: Why not simply "look on the conflict"? What does the extra *on* actually do?

Comment: As we are onlookers to the conflict.

Comment: Pursuing @AndrewLeach’s line of reasoning, why not simply “look **at** the conflict,” or even more simply, “**watch** the conflict”? Or “**witness** the conflict”? What’s your context? What, exactly, do you wish to mean? And do you, as you have written, actually “want” to use *look on*? Why?

Comment: "Look on" seems to emphasise passivity more than just "look" (most good dictionaries do have a separate entry for "look on"). But there are plenty of other, clearer and more expressive ways to emphasise the same thing, and most of them won't involve "on on".

Comment: "Look on" might imply passivity ("They ransack the place as we look on") but for **this** question Ozymandias might have some input: "Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair!". The second *on* appears to be superfluous; and if it isn't superfluous, what does "look on on the conflict" actually **mean**?

Comment: @Andrew Leach "look on" is an idiom with its own connotative meaning. It is not simply "look" + "on". Would it be "look on at" then?

Comment: @user84614 My previous comment answers that. However, you have still to answer what "look on on the conflict" actually means. I believe it's nonsense, which is why you're having difficulty with it.